# Can't insert from subsonic 2.2 to mysql (Joomla CMS database)

Tags: mysql, subsonic, joomla

I can't insert record into mysql database (joomla CMS table jos_content). Receive:
Exception:"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Any idea, what could be wrong, since I'm just copying all data except autoincremental from source record (same database, same table!)

```
//using Subsonic 2.2 , connecting to mysql server 5.1.33-community

//just to test that reading works OK
JosContentCollection jcc = new JosContentCollection().Load();  
foreach (var content in jcc)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(content.Id + " " + content.Title);  
}  
//foreach works OK... shows all records



JosContent jcSource = new JosContent(2);   //use previous record as source
Console.WriteLine("Read record:"+jcSource.Id + " " + cSource.Title);            
//read OK... record was found and shown!


JosContent jc= new JosContent();    
//all records copied from source record except autoincremental field
//jc.Id =   //auto increment field  
jc.Title = "test from c# "; // +DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();  
jc.AliasX = "test-from-c";  
jc.TitleAlias = jcSource.TitleAlias;  //String.Empty;  
jc.Introtext = jcSource.Introtext; // "short intro text";  
jc.Fulltext = jcSource.Introtext; // "long html";  
jc.State = jcSource.State; // true;  
jc.Sectionid = jcSource.Sectionid; // 1;  
jc.Mask = jcSource.Mask; //0;  
jc.Catid = jcSource.Catid;  
jc.Created = jcSource.Created; // DateTime.Now;  
jc.CreatedBy = jcSource.CreatedBy;   
jc.CreatedByAlias = jcSource.CreatedByAlias;  
jc.Modified = jcSource.Modified; // DateTime.Now;  
jc.ModifiedBy = jcSource.ModifiedBy;  
jc.CheckedOut = jc.CheckedOut;  
jc.CheckedOutTime = jcSource.CheckedOutTime; // DateTime.Now;  
jc.PublishUp = jcSource.PublishUp; // DateTime.Now;  
jc.PublishDown = jcSource.PublishDown; // DateTime.Now;  
jc.Images = jcSource.Images;   
jc.Urls = jcSource.Url;  
jc.Attribs = jcSource.Attribs;   
jc.Version = jc.Version;  
jc.Parentid = jc.Parentid;  
jc.Ordering = jc.Ordering;  
jc.Metakey = jcSource.Metakey;   
jc.Metadesc = jcSource.Metadesc;   
jc.Access = jcSource.Access;  
jc.Hits = jcSource.Hits;  
jc.Metadata = jcSource.Metadata;   


jc.Save();          //Generates exception:  
            /*
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled
  Message="You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fulltext,state,sectionid,mask,catid,created,created_by,created_by_alias,modified' at line 1"
  Source="MySql.Data"
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Number=1064
  StackTrace:
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.OpenPacket()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadResult(UInt64& affectedRows, Int64& lastInsertId)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetResultSet()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
       at SubSonic.MySqlDataProvider.ExecuteScalar(QueryCommand qry)
       at SubSonic.DataService.ExecuteScalar(QueryCommand cmd)
       at SubSonic.ActiveRecord`1.Save(String userName)
       at SubSonic.ActiveRecord`1.Save()
       at joomlamysqlapi.Program.VsaVsebina() in R:\joomlamysqlapi\Program.cs:line 114
       at joomlamysqlapi.Program.Main(String[] args) in R:\joomlamysqlapi\Program.cs:line 13
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `jos_content`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jos_content`;  
CREATE TABLE `jos_content` (  
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `title_alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `introtext` mediumtext NOT NULL, 
  `fulltext` mediumtext NOT NULL,  
  `state` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `sectionid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `mask` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `catid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
  `created_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `created_by_alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
  `modified_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `checked_out` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
  `publish_up` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
  `publish_down` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
  `images` text NOT NULL,  
  `urls` text NOT NULL,  
  `attribs` text NOT NULL,  
  `version` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
  `parentid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `metakey` text NOT NULL,  
  `metadesc` text NOT NULL,  
  `access` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `hits` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `metadata` text NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `idx_section` (`sectionid`),  
  KEY `idx_access` (`access`),  
  KEY `idx_checkout` (`checked_out`),  
  KEY `idx_state` (`state`),  
  KEY `idx_catid` (`catid`),  
  KEY `idx_createdby` (`created_by`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=58 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  
            */
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess two things:

1) mediumtext might not be recognized properly and typed in MySQL.tt. You might want to set a break point on Save() and see the SQL produced.

2) The unsigned stuff we've had problems with. The latest source should fix that (note: this doesn't mean 3.0.0.3 - it means the current source).

If there's anyway you can push the SQL using the debugger, it would help.